# Android list with one expandable item

Tags: android, list, expandable

is there possibility to make list with only one expandable item ? 
I found many samples and tutorials how to make expandable list with all items expandable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can use the ExpandableListView and the ExpandableListAdapter, and then implement the getChildrenCount method on ExpandableListAdapter this way:

```
@Override
public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {
    if(groupPosition == <THE EXPANDABLE POSITION>) {
         return <number of items>
    } else {
         return 0;
    }
}
```

Doing this, only the group in  will be expandable.